# failed to load config from C:\Users\92311\Videos\demo\vite.config.ts on run demo dev command in React Admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

```
`C:\Users\92311\Videos\demo>npm run dev
> demo@4.0.0 dev
> vite
```

```
failed to load config from C:\Users\92311\Videos\demo\vite.config.ts
error when starting dev server:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\92311\packages'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1072:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\92311\Videos\demo\vite.config.ts:37:34)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object._require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (file:///C:/Users/92311/Videos/demo/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5605cfa4.js:63154:24)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at loadConfigFromBundledFile (file:///C:/Users/92311/Videos/demo/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5605cfa4.js:63162:21)
    at loadConfigFromFile (file:///C:/Users/92311/Videos/demo/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5605cfa4.js:63020:34)
```

`

**When i pull the demo from react-admin repo and After install dev dependencies and hit npm run dev i found this error** im expecting to start

OS:Windows 11

NodeVersion : 14.10.0 (also tried till with latest version also).

Comment: Looks like you are running the demo outside of the project's original repository (which contains the 'packages' folder). This is not supported. You need to run the demo from the root of the react-admin workspace.

Comment: can you suggest me node version which can i use with this project

Comment: I'm using node v16.17.0

Comment: Thanks i run it very well as according to the given commands.

Comment: i need a favour so i have a project and demo depends on the packages that are in root folder how can i take out the demo from that directory and use it my own.  @slax57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So make commands is not working in windows for me what i did is

```
yarn install
```

on main/ root directory after that goes into each packages folder and run

```
yarn build
```

this what a make file do when you run `make install` or `make build`.

after that is run `yarn run-demo` and my project has been up!